# Loopback - EmbedsOne relation producing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have following two models

> Nurse
>
> Room

A room has belongsTo relation with the nurse model as defined below:

```
"relations": {
        "nurse": {
            "model": "Nurse",
            "type": "belongsTo",
            "foreignKey": "nid"
        }
    }
```

which works fine and produces the data on following urls

> http://localhost:3000/api/Rooms/1
>
> http://localhost:3000/api/Rooms/1/nurse

but when I try the embedsOne relation as defined below:

```
"relations": {
        "nurse": {
            "model": "Nurse",
            "type": "embedsOne",
            "foreignKey": "nid"
        }
    }
```

and try accessing url at

> http://localhost:3000/api/Rooms/1

I get the following error:

> message: "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '_nurse' in 'field list'",

thoughts?

Comment: Can you post your nurse.json and room.json files? I haven't been able to reproduce this with the information given.

Comment: I would suggest running your app setting a DEBUG='loopback:relation' flag to get more info about the problem.

Comment: Also a good idea to fork [the loopback-sandbox](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sandbox) and reproduce the issue in there so someone can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

embedsOne relation does not have foreignKey. You should use "property" as is shown in documentation: (https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Embedded+models+and+relations#Embeddedmodelsandrelations-EmbedsOne)

```
"relations": {
  "address": {
    "type": "embedsOne",
    "model": "Address",
    "property": "billingAddress"
  }
}
```

then your object will look like

```
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'John Smith',
  billingAddress: {
    street: '123 Main St',
    city: 'San Jose',
    state: 'CA',
    zipCode: '95124'
  }
}
```